# Pinch a specific point and zoom a whole view?

Tags: android, apache-flex, text, zooming, pinch

im trying to get a zoom for my mobile android project. The thing is, I want to point with two fingers a specific position and pinch them to zoom (not just only an image, the whole active view):

```
private function onGestureZoom(event:TransformGestureEvent):void{
    if(canvas.scaleY.valueOf() >= 1) {
        canvas.scaleX *= event.scaleX;
        canvas.scaleY *= event.scaleY;
    } else {
        canvas.scaleX = 1;
        canvas.scaleY = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ever make any progress on this, I'm currently facing a similar issue?  So far I've been using the transform.matrix of my display object to adjust the tx and ty values, then scale then reset the tx ty values.  This is almost working, however determining how much to offset as the object is scaling has posed difficult.

Comment: Actually just figured this out not sure if you're still around or it's relevant but I'll post an answer anyhow.  Granted my initial approach is different so you'll have to adapt for your own solution, I used the raw TouchEvents.

Answer (score 0):

This answer includes two classes (of interest) I've written that helped to abstract the problem to re-use some of the functionality.  I included ToolBase here as well although it's not as important to understand the issue.  Basically MultiTouchTool.as is setup to capture the TouchEvents and keep track of them in an object, it also calls some methods based on some common actions I need to know about for my use cases (I just extend this class and override the methods I want hooks for).

The key elements then are in NavigatorTool.as which uses the objects original transform matrix and adjusts the translation then does the scaling then readjusts the translation.  This effectively moved the registration point.  So the image is shifted up and to the left so the point between the two fingers is now at the top left, then the image is scaled and it's position is reset.  Since the scaling is happening in an incremental fashion I keep updating the intialDistance (the name may be misleading).

In my case I'm scaling an object called layerM which is a Sprite, but any [DisplayObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#transform) will work.

[MultiTouchTool.as]

```
package com.shaunhusain.fingerPainting.tools
{
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.TouchEvent;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    public class MultiTouchTool extends ToolBase implements ITool
    {
        protected var pointsTracked:Number = 0;
        protected var ptsTracked:Object;
        public function MultiTouchTool(stage:Stage)
        {
            super(stage);
            ptsTracked = {};
        }

        public function takeAction(event:TouchEvent=null):void
        {
            switch(event.type)
            {
                case TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN:
                    ptsTracked[event.touchPointID] =  new Point(event.stageX, event.stageY);
                    pointsTracked++;
                    if(pointsTracked>1)
                        secondFingerDown();
                    break;

                case TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE:
                    switch(pointsTracked)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            oneFingerMoving(event);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            twoFingersMoving(event);
                            break;

                    }
                    ptsTracked[event.touchPointID] =  new Point(event.stageX, event.stageY);
                    break;

                case TouchEvent.TOUCH_END:
                case TouchEvent.TOUCH_ROLL_OUT:
                    switch(pointsTracked)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            oneFingerEnd();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            twoFingerEnd();
                            break;
                    }


                    ptsTracked[event.touchPointID] = null;
                    pointsTracked--;
                    if(pointsTracked<0)
                        pointsTracked = 0;
                    break;
            }
        }

        protected function oneFingerEnd():void
        {
            trace("default handler for one finger end, not overridden");
        }
        protected function twoFingerEnd():void
        {
            trace("default handler for two finger end, not overridden");
        }
        protected function oneFingerMoving(event:TouchEvent):void
        {
            trace("default handler for one finger moving, not overridden");
        }
        protected function twoFingersMoving(event:TouchEvent):void
        {
            trace("default handler for two fingers moving, not overridden");
        }
        protected function secondFingerDown():void
        {
            trace("default handler for second finger down, not overridden");
        }

        public function toString():String
        {
            return "Multi-Touch tool";
        }
    }
}
```

[NavigatorTool.as]

```
package com.shaunhusain.fingerPainting.tools 
{
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.TouchEvent;
    import flash.geom.Matrix;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    /**
     * Allows the layer manager to be panned and zoomed on, other tools are
     * responsible for taking into account the current zoom and pan position
     * when modifying the layers.
     */
    public class NavigationTool extends MultiTouchTool implements ITool
    {
        private var initialDistance:Number;
        private var newDistance:Number;
        private var layerLocal:Point;
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //              Constructor
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public function NavigationTool(stage:Stage)
        {
            super(stage);
        }


        override public function toString():String
        {
            return "Navigation";
        }

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //              Overrides
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        override protected function oneFingerMoving(event:TouchEvent):void
        {
            var currentTouchPrevPos:Point = ptsTracked[event.touchPointID];
            var offset:Point = new Point(event.stageX-currentTouchPrevPos.x,event.stageY-currentTouchPrevPos.y);
            layerM.x += offset.x;
            layerM.y += offset.y;
        }
        override protected function twoFingersMoving(event:TouchEvent):void
        {
            if(isNaN(initialDistance))
            {
                initialDistance = Point.distance(ptsTracked[0],ptsTracked[1]);
                layerLocal = new Point((ptsTracked[0].x+ptsTracked[1].x)/2,(ptsTracked[0].y+ptsTracked[1].y)/2);
            }
            else
            {
                newDistance = Point.distance(ptsTracked[0],ptsTracked[1]);

                var matrix:Matrix = layerM.transform.concatenatedMatrix.clone();

                matrix.tx -= layerLocal.x;
                matrix.ty -= layerLocal.y;
                matrix.scale(newDistance/initialDistance,newDistance/initialDistance);
                matrix.tx += layerLocal.x;
                matrix.ty += layerLocal.y;

                layerM.transform.matrix = matrix;

                initialDistance = newDistance;
            }
        }
        override protected function twoFingerEnd():void
        {
            initialDistance = NaN;
        }

    }
}
```

[ToolBase.as]

```
package com.shaunhusain.fingerPainting.tools
{
    import com.shaunhusain.fingerPainting.view.managers.LayerManager;
    import com.shaunhusain.fingerPainting.view.managers.SecondaryPanelManager;
    import com.shaunhusain.fingerPainting.managers.UndoManager;
    import com.shaunhusain.fingerPainting.model.PaintModel;

    import flash.display.Stage;

    /**
     * Base class for tools to give them all easy access to the Singletons and
     * the Stage.
     */
    public class ToolBase
    {
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //              Variables
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        protected var model:PaintModel = PaintModel.getInstance();
        protected var undoManager:UndoManager = UndoManager.getIntance();
        protected var secondaryPanelManager:SecondaryPanelManager = SecondaryPanelManager.getIntance();
        protected var layerM:LayerManager = LayerManager.getIntance();
        protected var stage:Stage;

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //              Constructor
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public function ToolBase(stage:Stage)
        {
            this.stage = stage;
        }
    }
}
```